# I can't get wanted parameters through the json response (web-scraping)

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract data through the json response of this link : https://www.bienici.com/recherche/achat/france?page=2

I have 2 problems:
- first, I want scrape a house's parametrs like (price, area, city, zip code) but I don't know how ?
- Secondly, I want to make a loop that goes all the pages up to page 100

This is the program :

```
 import requests
 from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
 import csv

 payload = {'filters': '{"size":24,"from":0,"filterType":"buy","newProperty":false,"page":2,"resultsPerPage":24,"maxAuthorizedResults":2400,"sortBy":"relevance","sortOrder":"desc","onTheMarket":[true],"limit":"ih{eIzjhZ?q}qrAzaf}AlrD?rvfrA","showAllModels":false,"blurInfoType":["disk","exact"]}'}

 url = 'https://www.bienici.com/realEstateAds.json'  
 response = requests.get(url, params = payload).json()
 with open("selog.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)

     for prop in response['realEstateAds']:
         title = prop['title']
         city = prop['city']
         desc = prop['description']
         price = prop['price']

         df = json_normalize(response['realEstateAds'])
         df.to_csv('selog.csv', index=False)
         writer.writerow([price,title,city,desc])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi first thing I notice is you're writing the csv twice. Once with `writer` and once with `.to_csv()`. Depending what you are trying to do, you don't need both, but ultimately either would work. It just depends then how you iterated through the data.

Personally, I like working with pandas. I’ve had people tell me it’s a little overkill to store temp dataframes and append to a “final” dataframe, but it’s just what I’m comfortable doing and haven’t had issues with it, so I just used that.

To get other data parts, you'll need to investigate what’s all there and work your way through the json format to pull that out of the json response (if you’re going the route of using csv writer).

The pages are part of the payload parameters. To go through pages, just iterate that. The weird thing is, when I tried that, not only do you have to iterate through `pages`, but also the `from` parameter. Ie. since I have it doing 60 per page, page 1 is from 0, page 2 is from 60, page 3 is from 120, etc. So had it iterate through those multiples of 60 (it seems to get it). Sometimes it’s possible to see how many pages you’ll iterate through, but I couldn’t find it, so simply left it as a try/except, so when it reaches the end, it’ll break the loop. The only downside, is it could draw an error unexpected before, causing it to stop pre-maturely. I didn’t look too much into that, but just as a side note.

so it would look something like this (might take a while to go through all the pages, so I just did pages 1-10$:

You can also before saving to csv, manipulte the dataframe to keep only the columns you want:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

tot_pages = 10

url = 'https://www.bienici.com/realEstateAds.json'  

results_df = pd.DataFrame()

for page in range(1, tot_pages+1):

    try:
        payload = {'filters': '{"size":60,"from":%s,"filterType":"buy","newProperty":false,"page":%s,"resultsPerPage":60,"maxAuthorizedResults":2400,"sortBy":"relevance","sortOrder":"desc","onTheMarket":[true],"limit":"ih{eIzjhZ?q}qrAzaf}AlrD?rvfrA","showAllModels":false,"blurInfoType":["disk","exact"]}' %((60 * (page-1)), page)}
        response = requests.get(url, params = payload).json()

        print ('Processing Page: %s' %page)
        temp_df = json_normalize(response['realEstateAds'])

        results_df = results_df.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)
    except:
        print ('No more pages.')
        break

# To Filter out to certain columns, un-comment below
#results_df = results_df[['city','district.name','postalCode','price','propertyType','surfaceArea','bedroomsQuantity','bathroomsQuantity']]

results_df.to_csv('selog.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
    print(results_df.head(5).to_string())
             city                    district.name postalCode   price propertyType  surfaceArea  bedroomsQuantity  bathroomsQuantity
0        Colombes   Colombes - Fossés Jean Bouvier      92700  469000         flat        92.00               3.0                1.0
1            Nice   Nice - Parc Impérial - Le Piol      06000  215000         flat        49.05               1.0                NaN
2            Nice                  Nice - Gambetta      06000  145000         flat        21.57               0.0                NaN
3  Cagnes-sur-Mer  Cagnes-sur-Mer - Les Bréguières      06800  770000        house       117.00               3.0                3.0
4             Pau                  Pau - Le Hameau      64000  310000        house       110.00               3.0                2.0
```